# NullPointerException when testing service containing mocked JPA repository

Tags: java, spring, mocking, mockito

I am working on my first spring boot project and I am having trouble with testing my class as a Mockito newbie.
I need to check that the findAndUpdateUser method below update User entity fields correctly :

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;

    public User findUser(String id) {
        return userRepo.findById(id);
    }

    public User findAndUpdateUser(String id) {
        User foundUser = findUser(id);
        //some update on foundUser fields
        return foundUser;
    }
}
```

To test, I need to mock entity bean because I don't have DB locally. Here is my test class :

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class UpdateFieldsTest {
    @Mock
    private UserRepository userRepo;

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        User user = new User();
        user.setId("testId");
        //setting some other user fields

        Mockito.when(userRepo.findById("testId")).thenReturn(user);
        UserServiceImpl userService = new userServiceImpl();
        User returnedUser = userService.findAndUpdateUser("testId");

        //Checking if user field values are updated after findAndUpdate call
        Assert.xxx
        //other asserts
    }
}
```

But this code throw me some NullPointerException on method call. I even tried to mock findUser method but I still have error...

Am I having a bad approach ? How should I test my method ?

Any help is welcomed
Thanks all

Comment: 1. Full stacktrace is usually helpful for debugging NPE. 2. You never infect that dependancy. You should pass `userRepo` into `userService` either via constructor or via a setter.

Comment: You're instanciating the `UserServiceImpl` which autowires a `UserRepository` I suppose? You cannot do it like that. If you don't let the framework handle the way your service is instanciated, the DI expressed through `@Autowired` annotations will not work. Probably the cause of the NPE. Mockito provides some mechanism to handle DI with mocked instances. You can take a look at `@InjectMocks` f.ex.

Comment: @Imaguest Yes exactly. I will check the InjectMocks annotation that i did not know. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using this instantiation UserServiceImpl userService = new userServiceImpl(); make the UserRepo null;

you are using mockito, so you can use

 `@InjectMocks 
 private UserServiceImpl;` and delete the instastiation line.

Comment: wow, thanks. So Mockito automatically bind UserRepo dependency to the corresponding service just through the annotation ! That's powerful ! Thanks again !

Answer (score 2):

Mocks won't magicly appear inside of your object. You need to inject them manually. In you test, inside of the `userService`, the `userRepo` will be null. You inject dependancies either by constructor or by setter. It would look like this in your test:

```
UserServiceImpl userService = new userServiceImpl(userRepo);
```

Or

```
UserServiceImpl userService = new userServiceImpl();
userService.setUserRepo(userRepo);
```

Comment: thanks, I am gonna try this

Comment: can you share findAndUpdateUser function ?
 I guess, after calling findById, you call an other function (save, saveOrUpdate ...). 
In thiis case the second method return a null, you should mock it.

Comment: findAndUpdateUser basically call findUser then update 1 user fields through setter (in this case user.setLastConsultDate(now()) & then return the object